# Username from django auth_user as foreign key in another table

Tags: python, django, database, forms, foreign-keys

I have this model:

models.py

```
class InsertIP(models.Model):
    sourceIP=models.CharField(max_length=18)
    destinationIP=models.CharField(max_length=18)
    port=models.CharField(max_length=10)
    comment=models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
       db_table="fw_rules"
```

And I need to add column User which contains the name of user who creates the record. I need to create foreign key from username from django auth_user

Can you please help me?

Thank you.

Comment: you can directly link user model as foreign key to your model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
class InsertIP(models.Model):
    sourceIP = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    destinationIP = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    port = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
       db_table="fw_rules"
```

Then in your view you will access it like this:

```
ip = InsertIp.objects.get(pk=pk) # query the InsertIp object
user = ip.user # get the user using a . operator
```

Comment: dont forget to run `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate` to apply changes to your models, cheers!